# How do I create a column that tells me whether or not another column contains alpha numeric values?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have multiple datasets containing a common column - GuestCode. For all datasets, I want to create another column that tells me whether or not GuestCode contains letters in each row.

I was able to do this successfully for one of the datasets using the code below:

```
df['TestResult'] = df['GuestCode'].str.contains(r"[^a-zA-Z\s']", regex=True)
```

| GuestCode | TestResult |
| --- | --- |
| 5885 | nan |
| CCM6505 | True |

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this worked because in this dataset, GuestCode was read as an 'object' datatype in the dataframe.

However, when I try the same code on a dataset that contains only numeric values in GuestCode, the same code doesn't work because GuestCode gets read as a 'float'. After receiving an

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

I modify the code, but I don't get the correct result.

```
df['TestResult'] = df['GuestCode'].astype(str).str.contains(r"[^a-zA-Z\s']", regex=True)
```

| GuestCode | TestResult |
| --- | --- |
| 4445 | True |
| CCM6515 | True |

I'm not married to the regex solution, I just need a way to successfully identify whether or not a I have alphabet characters in the GuestCode column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if each row contains letters you can use:

```
df['TestResult'] = df['GuestCode'].astype(str).str.contains('[A-Za-z]')
```

To check if all the characters are alphabet letters you can use:

```
df['TestResult'] = df['GuestCode'].astype(str).str.isalpha()
```

Answer (score 1):

The character class `[^a-zA-Z\s']` matches a single character other than a-zA-Z, a whitespace char or `'`

If you just want to check for characters A-Za-z you can use

```
df['TestResult'] = df['GuestCode'].astype(str).str.contains(r"[a-zA-Z]", regex=True)
```

or

```
df['TestResult'] = df['GuestCode'].astype(str).str.match(r"[a-zA-Z]")
```

Output

```
  GuestCode  TestResult
0      4445       False
1   CCM6515        True
```